# JavaScript ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, html, security, firefox, activexobject

I have a queastion about ActiveXObject in javascript. I have tryed this code in Mozila FireFox 6.0.2

```
var AXobj = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
AXobj.SendKeys(key);
```

But the error console says that ActiveXObject is undefined. After that, I have tryed this:

```
var AXobj = new DOMParser("WScript.Shell");
AXobj.SendKeys(key);
```

But then, the error console says:

> Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Security error"  code: "1000" nsresult: "0x805303e8 (NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR)"  location: "file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Guest/Desktop/stuff/html/GML%20to%20JS.html Line: 335"]

By the way, i don't want to use ActiveXObject only for SendKeys. I need it for more stuff (like writing in file... ) AND, the reason i use FireFox instead of IE is that FireFox supports HTML5.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ActiveX is a proprietary technology only supported by Microsoft...

It will only work in IE (*thank goodness*).

It also has some serious security concerns which is a big reason it was never adopted by other browser providers.

Comment: +1 I sleep well every night knowing that I will never have to worry about ActiveX running on my systems.

Comment: So ActiveXObject doesn't work in other explorers than IE.
This means I'm stuck. Other borowsers are supporting <canvas>, but not ActiveXObject. IE supports ActiveXObject, but not <canvas>. IE9 has both, but it's for Windows 7, and iI have XP. :/ Too bad

Answer (score 1):

For this you can check if it is IE then do this otherwise
do that.

Like:

```
Function exampleFunction()
{
if ($.browser.msie) { /* IE */
                //Your code

            else {
                //Your code
            }
}
```

just a suggestion.