# JavaScript to set field in Lotus Notes Web Form

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes

I am trying to have a Wscript agent run when the web form starts in order to set a field with the machine name.  I have tried adding this as pass through HTML at the bottom of the form as well as adding it to the `onLoad` event or the `JS Header` to no avail.  I am a beginner at web enabling a form and adding JavaScript to it in Lotus.  Any help would be fantastic.  Below is the code:

Field Name: MachineName

```
{
var ax = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");    
f.MachineName.value = ax.ComputerName;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is not the complete code. At least one line is missing that defines "f"

The curly brackets have no sense in your code...

In the onload- event of the form, this code should work:

```
var f=document.forms[0];
var ax = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Network" );
f.MachineName.value = ax.ComputerName;
```

Of course this will only work in InternetExplorer as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421231/javascript-activexobject)

Comment: Hey TodeI copy and pasted it just as you have here into the onload event and have it set to run as Web JavaScript but so far it is not working.  Not sure why.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot and had changed the field name.  Works perfectly.  Thank you!